# how to dock elements in html using css

Tags: html, css

i have a main div whose css is :

```
.major
{
width:30%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

now i want to inset an web info at the bottom part which is like

about | terms | Policies | Contact us

this div is .web_info

so my html is

```
<div class="major">
<div class="web_info"></div>
</div>
```

Now i want the web_info div to appear always at the bottom of the parent div i.e "major" ..

i have treid :

```
.web_info
{
padding-top:90%;
}
```

But the solution isn't general .. i.e compactible for my screen only .. What to do ??

Comment: Try making .major `position: relative` and putting `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on your web_info div

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this one?

```
.web_info {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

So the Div "docks" always at the bottom of the parent div. 
Important, to get this work the parent div major must have the

```
position:relative;
```

property.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another HTML element to set a relative position :

```
<div class="major">
  <div class="innerRelative">
    <div class="web_info"></div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/A4GNs/